# Баг Vue в Webstorm

Tags: vue.js, webstorm, vue-cli

Когда открываю один из .vue компонентов в Webstorm, наблюдаю такую картину, хотя до этого там был код компонента. Подскажите, как исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на картинке скорее `package.json`, а не vue компонент. Вы уверены, что случайно не переписали содержимое файла? И что будет, если его же открыть в другом редакторе?

Comment: @lena содержимое файла не переписывал, в VS Code открылся vue компонент

Comment: более чем странно, никогда с таким не сталкивалась. Если инвалидация кэшей не поможет, проверьте, что файл, который вы открываете в других редакторах, действительно тот самый, что открыт в webstorm

Comment: @lena ничего не сработало, я просто удалил этот файл и сделал git pull